# Get value from eventEmitter from directive without HTML Template

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

First of all, sorry if this is a duplicate. I've been looking for some answers but have found none. Let me explain my problem.

I have a directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myOwnDirective]',
})
export class MyOwnDirective {
  @Input() set myOwnDirective(value: string) {
    // do Something
  }
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  
  // Some more logic which will at some moment trigger the EventEmitter

}
```

And I want to inject this directive to a custom component via hostBinding.

```
export class MyOwnComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('attr.myOwnDirective') myOwnDirective = new MyOwnDirective(this.el);

  constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myOwnDirective.myOwnDirective = 'someValue';
  }
```

As you can see, in the ngOnInit hook I am able to set the @Input parameter from the directive, as I would usually do in the HTML Template using []. **However how would I be able to catch the values emitted via the EventEmitter**?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the default approach within the HTML?

Comment: I cannot do that since one of the places I must use this directive is being rendered using the ComponentFactoryResolver, thus the element is not locatable in an HTML Template

Answer (score 0):

First of all, creating a directive with the new operator isn't recommended, the Directive will never be injected into the Angular DI. (but it's a future feature that the Angular team is considering https://angular.io/guide/roadmap#support-adding-directives-to-host-elements)

For your problem, you cannot just subscribe to the EventEmitter ?

```
this.myOwnDirective.valueChange.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

Comment: I have tried that and I am not able to catch the event, but I think that it has to do with the fact that for some reasons when injecting the directive with the new operator, it is not working well.